# num2persian Failed to minify the code from this file: ./node_modules/num2persian

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm using `num2persian` for converting numbers to persian characters. When I execute the command `npm run build` the following error is throw:

> Failed to minify the code from this file:
>
> ./node_modules/num2persian/src/num2persian.js:50

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just upgrade react-scripts to version > 2